# Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no win32com in java.library.path

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication, javax.comm

I have a small piece of code that requires [javax.comm](http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip) api for serial port communication. This is what i have done.

Placed the comm.jar file in the jre/lib/ext directory.

Placed the javax.comm.properties file in the jre/lib directory.

Placed the win32com.dll in the jre/bin directory.

But am getting an error

```
Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no win32com in java.library.path.
```

Am i missing some thing?

Answer (score 0):

I stucked in the same problem. I found a rar which contains javax.comm, but I won't work on 64bit OS I guess. But if you want to try, here the installing instruction from archive:

1. Copy the  "[ comm.jar ]" in to

   %JAVA_HOME%/lib

   %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext

2.Copy the " [ win32com.dll ] " in to

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin

%JAVA_HOME%/jre/bin

%windir%System32
```

3. Copy the " [ javax.comm.properties ] " in to

   %JAVA_HOME%/lib

   %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib